# Java Unicode strings sorting

Tags: java, string, unicode, collation, unicode-string

In Java, how does Unicode strings get compared?

What I mean is, if I have a few say, Japanese strings, when I do the following:

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(arrayOfJapaneseStrings);
```

how does those strings get compared and sorted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, Strings sort lexicographically, by Unicode order. The order is by UTF-16, so might not be exactly what you want for certain characters, but Japanese characters are all in the [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), so you shouldn't have a problem with these.

If you would like a different sort order, you can use the `java.text.Collator` classes to define a different sort order.

Comment: So the 'Unicode order' is basically 'Ascending Unicode code point' ?

Comment: @ryanprayogo: yes. To be specific, it is ascending Java character value, which because of UTF-16, are mostly mapped one-to-one with Unicode code points. Except for characters above U+10000, which use surrogate characters in their representation.

Comment: "Unicode order" follows the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Funicode.org%2Freports%2Ftr10%2F&ei=nDaNTaqGMoH2tgPUyNyDCQ&usg=AFQjCNHaqhYa1IL_sV1gHCDWNqYVY-WvcQ&sig2=mgtMSQCDljFjCCbeUbiRvQ).  You are talking about something different.  And please don’t talk about UTF-16; it’s a massive embarrassment and a royal pain in the posterior. Trying to deal with Unicode correctly in Java is excruciating torture.

Comment: Thanks, @tchrist. You are right, I didn't mean "Unicode order". I wasn't sure what to call it, since "code point order" would be misleading too. Maybe just "order of the numeric value of the characters".

Comment: BTW, I wasn't passing judgement on UTF-16 :-). Though I do give Java a lot of credit for bringing a practical version of Unicode into the language, when most languages still made it very difficult to work with even rudimentary Unicode. Even today, Java makes it very simple to work with most text, though for specialized use you do need to know what you are doing. I have yet to encounter a bug related to UTF-16 in Java.

Comment: @Avi: You want a UTF-16 bug in Java?  Ok here’s one: try matching three code points over U+010000 in a character class in a regular expression. But a bigger problem is that all the interfaces are screwy, being based on 16-bit code units not Unicode characters. So people mistake length() for codePointCount(), or use a char when only an int is big enough to hold a Unicode character.  A char is not.  A char should never be used to hold a character, because it is not big enough to do so.

Comment: Thanks, Tom - I wasn't aware of that particular regular expression issue. I just meant that *I* had never encountered a bug because of issues like this (and I work with a lot of text), not that bugs can't happen. You are certainly right in how chars should be treated. In general, though, even a full UTF-32 implementation would be confusing for users thinking that every unit corresponded to a character, because of things like combining characters, joining characters, etc.

Comment: @Avi, while I find that handling logical characters instead of encoding forms is just about infinitely preferable, you are very much correct that things like multi-code-point graphemes, invisible code points, and default ignorable code points all have the potential for a lot of confusion. The end-user nearly always wants to deal with graphemes, not code points, and the programmers must be rather careful to make sure that all works out properly.

Comment: To Java's defense: Early versions of Unicode were 16 bit. When Unicode 'upgraded' to 32 bit Java had a problem.

Answer (score 2):

By default it's in UTF-16 byte-code comparison. This is the fastest way, and hence perfect if all you need is **some** order (e.g. if you are going to use a binary search later, you need them to be in order, but just what "in order" means doesn't matter, so the faster the better).

If you need an ordering that is sensible to a user in a given locale, use the java.text.Collator class.

Comment: The j.t.Collator class does not comply with the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Funicode.org%2Freports%2Ftr10%2F&ei=nDaNTaqGMoH2tgPUyNyDCQ&usg=AFQjCNHaqhYa1IL_sV1gHCDWNqYVY-WvcQ&sig2=mgtMSQCDljFjCCbeUbiRvQ).  Use the real thing.

Comment: @tchrist is there a good support for the UCA now, with plenty of supported locales? The last time I actually used Java the UCA was quite new, so I know a lot has changed since (why I only rarely answer Java questions, just those I know I can say something meaningful on).

Comment: Jon, the JDK Collator class still does **not** implement the UCA, but [ICU’s](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Collator.html) does. I find that the UCA is usually just what I want, without even any special locales, but ICU also uses the CLDR data for its locale business if you would like. I use the UCA for all my text sorts now, and has it made a big difference.

Comment: @tchrist, I used some of the ICU stuff for C++ some times ago, and found it very good indeed.

Answer (score 0):

According to `compareTo` methodof String class. See the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29):

> Compares two strings
>   lexicographically. The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in
>        the strings. The character sequence represented by this
>        `String` object is compared lexicographically to the
>        character sequence represented by the argument string. The result is
>        a negative integer if this `String` object
>        lexicographically precedes the argument string. The result is a
>        positive integer if this `String` object
>   lexicographically
>        follows the argument string. The result is zero if the strings
>        are equal; `compareTo` returns
>   `0` exactly when
>        the {@link #equals(Object)} method would return `true`.

Comment: That looks like it’s ancient verbiage from the Bad Old Days of UCS-2.