# How to sort with accents in Java

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

First some code I am trying to sort with bubble this is what I have. It also has spanish words that have accents how can I sort with that? Thanks.

```
public static void bubble(String[] word) {
    for(int i = word.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if(word[j].compareToIgnoreCase(word[j + 1]) > 0) {
          String temp = word[j];
          word[j] = word[j + 1];
          word[j + 1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
      for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        System.out.println(word[i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: How do you want accented characters to be treated? Exactly the same as their non-accented counterparts, or as if they were an adjacent character in the alphabet?

Comment: Adjacent character in the Alphabet for example I know that in the spanish alphabet it is n then ñ. I am trying to sort as txt file that has both english and spanish words with Capital letter, accents, and dashes.

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433027/java-unicode-strings-sorting

Comment: You'll need to write a custom comparator.  I'm sure someone out there already has.

Comment: Take a look at the approved answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947700/traditional-spanish-sorting-of-strings-in-java